# Interfaces VS APIs VS Public classes

Tags: java, oop, interface, public

I am a little bit confused about the meaning and the differences between these three terms.

1. Interfaces
2. APIs
3. Public classes

I asked before if there is any difference between APIs and Public classes. Here is the question:
[Public methods vs public APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62185027/public-methods-vs-public-apis)

I got it, but now with the new concept *Interface*, I got confused again about the differences between Interface and API and Public class, so to make things clearer, let's see this sentence:

> Information hiding allows developers to work on modules separately, without needing other developers to know the implementation details of the module they are working on. The module is instead used through its interface.

What is the meaning of interface here? Is it the same as public class?

Comment: "Interface" in Java typically refers to the `interface` keyword.  It's one way of implementing an API.  However in that sentence, "interface" is used generically and just means the same thing as "public API."

Comment: In this case `its interface` does not necessarily mean an implementation of a specific interface.  Imo, it means the way in which one obtains information from the class.  So a `getter()` hides how the information is stored and is part of the interface of the class that lets the user of the class access information.  The same thing for a `setter()`.  In both cases they may return or set an `integer` but internally the author of the class can store them however they want (e.g. a string perhaps).

Comment: What is the source of the quote?

Comment: @jaco0646 Object-Oriented Design by University of Alberta on coursera

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A big reason these terms are confusing is because they are keywords in Java **and** they have meaning in a general, language-agnostic context. What the terms mean in the general context of programming is slightly different from what the specific keywords mean in Java.

In general, the term *interface* is synonymous with *abstraction*. When you read, "Program to an interface" it means program to an abstraction. In Java, the `interface` keyword indicates a specific type of stateless abstraction, which is contrasted with `abstract class`. In general, both of these are abstractions and thus both are programming interfaces.

In general, the term *public* indicates any part of code that is visible to and used by clients outside of the development team. In Java, the `public` keyword indicates a specific access level between classes and members. Since clients may view and use `protected` members as well, these may also be considered *public* in the general context of programming. Effective Java uses the term *exported* to combine `public` and `protected` members. Note that in Java 9+ *modules* can be used to control access, so even `public` classes may not be exported and thus may not be *public* in the general sense.

The term *API* is not a Java keyword, so at least we have no language-specific ambiguity to contend with. It is typically used to mean *public API*, which is synonymous with *exported API*. It is the sum of everything that you (the developer) allow your clients to view and use. Occasionally, the term *internal API* is used to indicate the opposite: classes and members that you do not allow your clients to view or use.